# Inner joined same query returns more result than when it's executed alone

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I don't know if I'm wrong but I've always thought (and I still do) that the number of records returned from querying a table alone and inner join the same table and querying this relation would be the same. Like this:

```
select 'foo' foo from dual;
```

**versus**

```
select * from (select 'foo' foo from dual)q1 inner join
(select 'foo' foo from dual)q2
 on q1.foo=q2.foo
```

Both these queries return one record. But I have a query when I inner join it with itself I get more records . Here's my query:

```
SELECT distinct DOC.DOCID
FROM AG_INW_DOC DOC
JOIN LAG_CITIZENS CIT
ON DOC.CITIZENID=CIT.CITIZENID
JOIN
  (SELECT TSK.DOCID,
    OFCR.DEPID
  FROM AG_TASKS TSK
  JOIN AG_TASK_EXECUTORS EXEC
  ON TSK.TASKID=EXEC.TASKID
  JOIN AG_OFFICERS OFCR
  ON EXEC.ISSUEDOFFICERID   =OFCR.OFFICERID
  WHERE EXEC.ISMAINEXECUTOR =1

  )TSK ON DOC.DOCID         =TSK.DOCID
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT ESCDOCID, UNDERCONTROL,ORGID FROM AG_ESCORTING_DOCUMENTS
  ) ESC
ON DOC.ESCDOCID       =ESC.ESCDOCID
WHERE DOC.CATEGORYID IN (11,12)
AND TRUNC(DOC.RECEIVEDDATE,'DDD') BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.11.2015') AND TO_DATE('30.11.2015')
AND (TSK.DEPID      IN ('017','004')
OR (TSK.DEPID        ='008'
AND DOC.SUBJECTID   IN (1,2,3,4,20,22,23,24) ))
AND DOC.DOCSTAT!     =3

UNION ALL
SELECT distinct  DOC.DOCID
FROM AG_INW_DOC DOC
JOIN LAG_CITIZENS CIT
ON DOC.CITIZENID=CIT.CITIZENID
LEFT JOIN AG_TASKS TSK
ON DOC.DOCID =TSK.DOCID
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT ESCDOCID, UNDERCONTROL,ORGID FROM AG_ESCORTING_DOCUMENTS
  ) ESC
ON DOC.ESCDOCID             =ESC.ESCDOCID
WHERE DOC.CATEGORYID       IN (11,12)
AND DOC.ADDRESSEDOFFICERID IN (9,26)
AND TRUNC(DOC.RECEIVEDDATE,'DDD') BETWEEN TO_DATE('01.11.2015') AND TO_DATE('30.11.2015')
AND DOC.DOCSTAT!          =3
```

If I run this query alone I get 3019 records returned. But if I `inner join` it with itself and select from this join I get 3023 records.

Now, I don't expect anyone to examine my query and point out the problem. I just need to know what circumstances might cause this behavior.

**EDIT**

The query returns only distinct values. No duplicates

Comment: Your query is a bit too massive to conclude anything without guessing. But in general, there's various joins out there. A LEFT JOIN will preserve all the data of the table on the left and TRY to join it to the table on the right with the `ON`. If the `ON` condition is false, then a LEFT JOIN will use NULL values for the table on the right. When you use an INNER JOIN, when an ON is false, it doesn't use NULL values, it skips the left table's record and the right table's record thus skipping to the next record for each table.

Comment: @Mikayil sorry, my first shot was too un-precise, I added update and hope this is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption holds only if you join on a primary or a unique key.

Here a small example that demonstrates the opposite:

This query gives two rows, but the key is not unique:

```
select 'foo, I''M no PK' foo from dual union all  
select 'foo, I''M no PK' foo from dual
;
```

Join of the above row source (using WITH) give 2 * 2 rows.

```
with dual2 as (
select 'foo, I''M no PK' foo from dual union all  
select 'foo, I''M no PK' foo from dual
)
select * from (select   foo from dual2)q1 inner join
(select   foo from dual2)q2
 on q1.foo=q2.foo
 ;
```

.

```
foo, I'M no PK  foo, I'M no PK
foo, I'M no PK  foo, I'M no PK
foo, I'M no PK  foo, I'M no PK
foo, I'M no PK  foo, I'M no PK
```

**UPDATE**

The above assumption is valid, but not relevant for this question.

The problem is in the construction `DISTINCT  UNION ALL  DISTINCT`

This may pass dups - the `UNION` must be used instead.

Example

```
with tab1 as ( 
select 1 foo  from dual union all  
select 1 foo  from dual union all
select 2 foo  from dual)
, tab2 as (
select 2 foo  from dual union all  
select 2 foo  from dual union all
select 3 foo  from dual)

select DISTINCT foo from tab1
UNION ALL
select DISTINCT foo from tab2
order by 1;
```

gives

```
1
2
2
3
```

Comment: Doesn't have to have a key, it is sufficient, that it actually is unique.

Answer (score 4):

Your assumption is wrong.

an inner join will combine every result from the first select with every result from the second select, and then filter for the join condition. So if your select returns a single column with the following three values:

```
1, 2, 2
```

A join with itself and the join condition that the values must be the same will yield

So you get 5 rows instead of 3.

Without looking at your actual select you probably have non-unique values in the columns of you join condition.

```
(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)
```

In order to find the duplicates wrap you complete query in something like this

```
select DOCID, count(*) from (
-- your query here
) group by DOCID
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: But there' no case like single column returning three values 1,2,2. The column values are distinct.

Comment: I can almost guarantee you there are duplicates. Check out my edit

Comment: I accept your guarantee :). You were correct. I was fooled by DISTINCT.